# how do I change 2 images with two sets of radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change to 2 different sets of images using 2 sets of radio button groupings. My code will change one group of images if only one set of radio buttons exists. When I add the second set radio buttons, both sets of radio buttons only change 1 image group. Sorry if I am not making sense.

Radio group 1

```
<input type="radio" name="barrel" class="color-picker" id="Black" value="Black" />
<input type="radio" name="barrel" class="color-picker" id="Carolina_Blue" value="Carolina_Blue" />
<input type="radio" name="barrel" class="color-picker" id="Charcoal" value="Charcoal" />
```

Radio group 2

```
<input type="radio" name="handle" class="color-picker" id="Black" value="Black" />
<input type="radio" name="handle" class="color-picker" id="Carolina_Blue" value="Carolina_Blue" />
<input type="radio" name="handle" class="color-picker" id="Charcoal" value="Charcoal" />
```

Here is my jQuery for group 1

```
    jQuery('input:radio[name="barrel"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() == 'Black'){
        jQuery('.barrel').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.nationalbatcompany.com/wp-content/themes/nationalbat/images/bats/barrels/black-barrel.png")'});
        jQuery('.customize-image .bat-text').css({'color':'#ffffff'});
    }
    else if ($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() == 'Carolina_Blue'){
        jQuery('.barrel').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.nationalbatcompany.com/wp-content/themes/nationalbat/images/bats/barrels/carolina-blue-barrel.png")'});
        jQuery('.customize-image .bat-text').css({'color':'#130F06'});
    }
    else if ($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() == 'Charcoal'){
        jQuery('.barrel').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.nationalbatcompany.com/wp-content/themes/nationalbat/images/bats/barrels/charcoal-barrel.png")'});
        jQuery('.customize-image .bat-text').css({'color':'#ffffff'});
    }
   });
```

Here is the jQuery for group 2

```
    jQuery('input:radio[name="handle"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() == 'Black'){
        jQuery('.handle').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.nationalbatcompany.com/wp-content/themes/nationalbat/images/bats/handles/black-handle.png")'});
    }
    else if ($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() == 'Carolina_Blue'){
        jQuery('.handle').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.nationalbatcompany.com/wp-content/themes/nationalbat/images/bats/handles/carolina-blue-handle.png")'});
    }
    else if ($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() == 'Charcoal'){
        jQuery('.handle').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.nationalbatcompany.com/wp-content/themes/nationalbat/images/bats/handles/charcoal-handle.png")'});
    }
    });
```

Here is a link to the site: http://www.nationalbatcompany.com/products/t-ball-bat/

If you click on Customize your bat you will see the barrel and handle colors. If you click on the barrel swatch colors the barrel image will change, if you click on the handle colors the barrel color will also change. This is not the intended function. The handle colors should change when the handle image swatch is clicked

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of linking to the site could you make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking at your code for a while I have no idea why it isn't working.  The problem is either in the event binding or, more likely, with the html (because clicking on the supposedly unrelated check boxes for handles changes the bat which is a different image and position entirely).  The bottom checkboxes are bound as if they are top.  I'll let you poke through that some more.

One thing I can offer to help with general debugging/code structure, you can reduce your barrel color changing code to be way more compact like this:

```
jQuery('input:radio[name="handle"]').change(function(){
    var color = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if ($(this).prop("checked")){
        jQuery('.handle').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.nationalbatcompany.com/wp-content/themes/nationalbat/images/bats/handles/' + color + '-handle.png")'});
    }
});
```

Then just throw a switch in there to swap the bat-text colors.  Anyway good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mike, but class .handle and .barrel is what is being changed. if you reference the URL to the site you will see that the plain bat image is actually 2 separate images. So you solution would not work.

Comment: @JosephGarcia actually...one question: how do you populate the form?  Is it dynamically generated in a post-process?